# heroku scheduler and python time.sleep()

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, scheduler

I wrote a Python script tweet weather on twitter every hour. and I use `time.sleep(3600)`. To make my bot work every hour. and I set Heroku Scheduler every hour too.

When I done this job. My bot does tweet a weather every hour but It work twice. What I mean, It tweeted weather tweet in 1:00 PM, and It tweeted weather tweet again in 1:01PM.

I think..

1. Heroku scheduler run my python script
2. and Heroku worker dyno run my python script again
   => So, it works twice an hour.

Is it right? then, Can I turn off my worker dyno(I mean, turn on only heroku scheduler add on) to prevent overlap work? I don't know what to do to prevent running python script tiwce an hour. help me..

Comment: Anyway, It works right when I turn on heroku scheduler only.